# specifying arrow direction

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 Eigen::Isometry3d pose1 = Eigen::Isometry3d::Identity();
                            pose1.translation() = p0;
                            visual_tools_->publishArrow(pose1, rvt::GREEN);
                            visual_tools_->trigger();
```

I am using rviz_visulization tool to pulibish some markes like plane, line list in rviz. Here how do i specify the direction of arrow in above code i.e in ros_visual_tools library?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355032/specifying-arrow-direction/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2020-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You only set the translation, but not the rotation (or rather, you set it to identity = no rotation).

Check [the example code](https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/rviz_visual_tools#example-code) on how to set the rotation of the pose...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2020-06-16**:
Is their also, built in function in rviz_visul tool to publish point or points with color? i tired publishing the rviz points marker from publishMarker but it is also showing the simlar problem i saw when using ros rviz marker i.e color is not comming. and also how to specify the arrow with two points?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-06-16**:
@dinesh, those are additional questions. Has the answer helped you? If yes, please mark as such and follow up with another question...